# Change height of cell with change frame of content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I can make animating of changing row height but it is bad with UITableViewRowAnimationFade, because it's flickers when animate

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Main VC";
    selectedIndexes = [NSMutableDictionary new];
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (BOOL)cellIsSelected:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSNumber *selectedIndex = [selectedIndexes objectForKey:indexPath];
return selectedIndex == nil ? NO : [selectedIndex boolValue];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static BOOL noFirst;
    if (!indexPath.row && !noFirst) {
        [selectedIndexes setObject:@(YES) forKey:indexPath];
        noFirst = YES;
    }
    if ([self cellIsSelected:indexPath]) {
        UIImage *cellImage = HelperDf.dataArray[indexPath.row][@"image"];
        CGFloat aspectRatioIndex =  cellImage.size.height / cellImage.size.width;
        return [Utils screenWidth:self.interfaceOrientation] * aspectRatioIndex;
    } else {
        return heightCell;
    }
}
```

My didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableSet *insideSet = [NSMutableSet new];
    [insideSet addObject:indexPath];
BOOL isSelected = ![self cellIsSelected:indexPath];
    for (NSIndexPath *keyIndexPath in selectedIndexes) {
        [insideSet addObject:keyIndexPath];
    }
    [selectedIndexes removeAllObjects];
[selectedIndexes setObject:@(isSelected) forKey:indexPath];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:insideSet.allObjects withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

So if I use  `[tableView beginUpdates] [tableView endUpdates` it is problems with change frame of my labels and `numberOfLinew`. How I can change frames of my labels and other parametres, that I change in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MainCell";
    MainCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = HelperDf.dataArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.titleLabel.text = dataDictionary[@"title"];
    cell.descriptionLabel.width = [Utils screenWidth:self.interfaceOrientation] - 40;
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = dataDictionary[@"fullText"];
    if ([self cellIsSelected:indexPath]) {
        cell.sequeBtn.hidden = NO;
        cell.pictureView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        cell.descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 7;
    } else {
        cell.sequeBtn.hidden = YES;
        cell.pictureView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        cell.descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    }
    [cell.descriptionLabel sizeToFit];
    cell.pictureView.image = dataDictionary[@"image"];
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MainCell *mainCell = (MainCell *)cell;
    mainCell.descriptionLabel.originY = mainCell.sequeBtn.hidden ? heightCell -  mainCell.descriptionLabel.height - 5 : mainCell.height - mainCell.sequeBtn.height - mainCell.descriptionLabel.height - 12;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code i used to set the UITableViewCell height dynamically:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   NSDictionary* dict = [branchesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSString* address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@\n%@\n%@\n%@",[dict objectForKey:@"locality"],[dict objectForKey:@"city"],[dict objectForKey:@"address"],[dict objectForKey:@"contactNumber"], [dict objectForKey:@"contactEmail"]];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(220, MAXFLOAT);

   CGSize size = [address sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

   CGFloat height1 = MAX(size.height, 110.0f);
   return height1+20;
}
```

as well as set the frame in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` also